# How to transfer opencv Mat over network?

Tags: c++, opencv, stream

I have just started working on a Robot controller,however I haven't got the camera part working. I want to receive  webcam stream over tcp from a server, which sends Mat[s], then display this information on the client side.

Either the server sends wrong information, potentially as a result of the cast, or the client interprets this information wrong, also potentially as a result of the cast. Either way I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

So far my server.cpp looks like this :

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 1111 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");

    VideoCapture cap;
    // open the default camera, use something different from 0 otherwise;
    // Check VideoCapture documentation.
    if(!cap.open(0))
        return 0;
    for(;;)
    {
          Mat frame;
          cap >> frame;
          if( frame.empty() ) break; // end of video stream
          //imshow("Input :)", frame);
          write(client_sock,(char *)frame.data,strlen((char *)frame.data));
          if( waitKey(1) == 27 ) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC 
    }
    // the camera will be closed automatically upon exit
    // cap.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And my client looks like this :

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main() {
    sf::TcpSocket socket;
    sf::Socket::Status status = socket.connect("127.0.0.1", 1111);
    if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        puts("Bye\n");
        return 0; 
    }
    while(true) {
        Mat frame;
        char data[1000000]; //strlen gave me around 930000 when I was debugging. 
        std::size_t received;

        // TCP socket:
        if (socket.receive(data, 1000000, received) != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            continue;
        }else {
            frame.data = (unsigned char *)data;
            imshow("Hello",frame); //Error occurs here, not sure what causes it 
        }
    }

}
```

Error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 269
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Aborted
```

Comment: Don't EVER call `strlen` on raw data. It simply returns the number of bytes before the first `\0` character (and might just as wel never terminate). It most definitely isn't the lenght of your array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you only send the `Mat`'s data. A `Mat` object contains header, which include, among other, the `Mat` size.

I'd suggest at the very least to also transmit the `Size` and `Type` of the Mat and then using it to create a new `Mat`

`Mat frame(receivedSize, receivedType)`

I'm not sure if that's would be enough, but that's a start.

Also, is there a reason you only send the `data` instead of  `(char *)&frame` and then casting it back to `Mat`?

Comment: I didn't really get it working, I managed to get information across and display it. But it was a really bad way of processing it as it rendered pixel by pixel, so it ended up being very ugly to look at.

Comment: I'm not sure how's this related? your question was about transmitting the data, how's rendering related?

Comment: I didn't know how to receive the frame on the client side. So what I did was to receive the data and write it pixel by pixel to a Mat. This was useless.